# Add Items of Multiple Orders into a Single Bill (Crystal Report)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm working in visual studio with vb.net and crystal report where I have few tables that store the order information of any restaurant. I want to print the bill of any order for the guest and also in case if guest has placed the order multiple times in a restaurant.

I'm attaching a image that will give you some sort of details about the scenario where 3 tables are designed with bill format as a output.

I want to use a record selection formula for any particular table to print the items details in Bill for all the order placed. Table 2 & 3 are linked to each other with 'Order No'. When I give the command to print the bill for table 'T1' it should give me the details as shown in the bill format which include all the order items from table 'TableOrderedItems' for the list of order numbers placed for that particular table (i.e. T1).

Firstly, I create a list of all orders that pertain to table # 'T1' like ("K1", "K2"). Then I will look into table 'TableOrderedItems' for each order no. in list and get printed all the items in bill (see image).`

```
Dim cryRptBill As New ReportDocument
Dim RepLocationBill As String
RepLocationBill = Application.StartupPath & "\CryRptBillTable.rpt"
cryRptBill.Load(RepLocationBill)
cryRptBill.RecordSelectionFormula = "{TableOrderedItems.OrderNumber}=" & " in [" + kotList + "]"
```

[Image For Tables & Bill Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS6oV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

CryRpt.RecordSelectionFotmula= "{tblUsers.ID} in [" + List + "]"

This assumes your list is a string with number and commas. For example "1, 3, 4"